# String constant pool, new object initialization (with new keyword) versus normal initialization of a string?

Tags: java, string

```
String s1 = new String("abc");
String s2 = "abc";
```

In `s1` there will be two objects created, one in the string pool and one in non-pool memory.

In `s2` there will be only one object created, in the string pool.

If we do:

```
s1.concat("def");
s2.concat("def");
```

There are now 3 objects in string pool (`"abc"`, `"def"`, and `"abcdef"`), two are abandoned (`"def"` and `"abcdef"`) leaving `"abc"` in memory.

Both references are referencing a string pool object.

What's the significance of memory object?

Comment: What do you mean "what's the significance of memory object?"?

Comment: Why do you think that *"abcdef"* will be in the string pool?

Comment: Nope. `"abcdef"` will not go into *String constants pool*.

Comment: Also, "abcdef" will be candidate for garbage-collection, because you're not assigning the result of concat() to any variable. concat() doesn't modify the string. It creates a new one.

Comment: i know about that thats why i asked.

Comment: @MarounMaroun its referencing only to the string pool then why make two objects one in heap and one in string pool while initiating first.

Comment: @Tom "abcdef" will go in string pool. Because thats how out BM handles String

Comment: @TheLostMind "abcdef" will go in string pool. Please check some basic java resources.

Comment: @JBNizet very true but its referencing only to the string pool then why make two objects one in heap and one in string pool while initiating first

Comment: @PurvenderHooda you seem be convinced that you know better than everyone out here. Then why are you asking? No, the result of s1.concat("def") won't go into the string pool. And I can't understand what you're asking me.

Comment: @PurvenderHooda - I am not talking about the *string literal* `"abcdef"`. I am talking about the string `abcdef` generated by `s1.concat("def")`. I assure you, it *does not* go into *String constats pool*.

Comment: @JBNizet Thats basics.Thanks anyways. I will find out that one. for a little proof:

Comment: @TheLostMind  
String s1 = new String("abc"); now do s1.concat("def"); , there is a change in object. so SOP(s1) should be "abcdef" not "abc". Please check first and then do reply.

Comment: @JBNizet  String s1 = new String("abc"); now do s1.concat("def"); , there is a change in object. so SOP(s1) should be "abcdef" not "abc". Please check first and then do reply.

Comment: Why don't you test by yourself first? BTW, you were already told twice that concat() doesn't change the string. It creates and returns a new one. SOP(s1) will not print "abcdef". It will print "abc.

Comment: @JBNizet I am asking you a very simple question: ie, at object creation if we wrote Strinf s1= new String("abc"); then there be object formation. Total 2 objects. s1 is referencing to object of pool or object of memory(JVM not pool). whats the significance of other object.

Comment: *"now do s1.concat("def"); , there is a change in object."* So you're telling us that `#concat` changes the _immutable_ String `s1`? Even the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29) proves you wrong.

Answer (score 4):

> In `s2` there will be only one object created, in the string pool.

Actually no, this line will create no new objects.  `s2` will be a reference to the same constant used to construct `s1`.

> There are now 3 objects in string pool (`"abc"`, `"def"`, and `"abcdef"`), two are abandoned (`"def"` and `"abcdef"`) leaving `"abc"` in memory.

No, only `"abc"` and `"def"` are in the constant pool, and since they are constants they will remain in memory for the duration of the program.  `"abcdef"` will be garbage collected promptly after it is constructed since it is never stored anywhere.

Had you used the `+` operator instead of `String.concat()` the compiler would in fact merge two constant strings into one, and only store the resulting string in the pool.

> Both references are referencing a string pool object.

No, only `s2` references a string in the constants pool, and neither result of `.concat()` will be in the constants pool.

> What's the significance of memory object?

Are you asking what the point of the string constants pool is?  It's essentially just an optimization to allow *constants* (i.e. `"`-ed strings in your code) to share the same reference to avoid constructing numerous identical instances.  Because they're constants, this can be done at compile-time, saving both space and time at runtime.  This does not apply to any strings constructed at runtime unless you explicitly call [`.intern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--), however you should generally [avoid doing so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7263399/113632).

You may also be interested in [Where does Java's String constant pool live, the heap or the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4918399/113632)

---

Edit: since you're insisting that `"abcdef"` in your example will be part of the constants pool, here's simple proof that is not the case:

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_02

$ cat Test.java
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "123" + "456";
    String s2 = "abc".concat("def");
  }
}

$ javac Test.java

$ javap -c -classpath . Test
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String 123456
       2: astore_1
       3: ldc           #3                  // String abc
       5: ldc           #4                  // String def
       7: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/String.concat:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
      10: astore_2
      11: return
}
```

As you can clearly see, the strings `123456`, `abc`, and `def` are constants (see [`ldc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings)), and `String.concat()` is called at runtime.

Comment: Note that in the given context `abc`, `def` , `123456` are *class constants* and *not constants of String constant pool*. i.e, A class constant != String constant pool (not always)

Answer (score 2):

[`s1.concat("def");`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat-java.lang.String-) and `s2.concat("def");` are happening at runtime, they won't be part of the constant pool, they goes to the *heap*.

Note the signature of `concat`:

```
public String concat(String str)
```

it returns a *new* string, and you're not assigning that string to any variable.

> What's the significance of memory object?

It's unclear what you're asking, but note that since the string created by `concat` is not assigned (references to it are discarded), it'll be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: They will be a part of string constant pool. we are not assigning any value, question is about total number of objects and where they reside in which memory.