# Why is String.intern() a native method?

Tags: java

What's the logic behind making this method native?

What is the advantage over just making the interned String pool with a hash map?

It looks a little strange, but it seems like it'd be pretty easy to do in non-native code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class String {

    // ...

    private final static HashMap<String, String> pool = new HashMap<>();

    public String intern() {

        if (pool.containsKey(this))
            return pool.get(this);

        synchronized (pool) {
            if (pool.containsKey(this))
                return pool.get(this);
            pool.put(this, this);
            return this;
        }

    }

    // ...

}
```

So why is it native code then?

Comment: The inner logic of `intern` is quite convoluted, in order to guarantee that it fulfills its contract in the face of all possible concurrent scenarios.  It's hard enough to do in C code, trust me.  (Keep in mind that a native method is no different from a regular Java method, aside from the fact that it's implemented in another language and has access to the inner workings of the JVM.)  (In fact, on the JVM I worked on some native methods WERE implemented in Java -- just given special privileges.)

Comment: @HotLicks I'd say it's easy in Java code, though. So why make it native? There's no performance increase, [that's for sure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624232/performance-penalty-of-string-intern).

Comment: Unless someone who was in the design process of Java posts an answer, your question is answerable in any definitive manner.

Comment: Maybe this question can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263399/why-is-string-intern-so-slow?rq=1

Comment: @JosephNields - You don't know what the synchronization complexities are.

Comment: @jdphenix - I wrote the C code for `intern` in the IBM AS400/iSeries JVM.  It's complicated.

Comment: @HotLicks what complicates it?

Comment: @JosephNields - Synchronization.  Not only with objects being created in multiple threads simultaneously, but also with GC running.

Comment: @HotLicks ah, yes, because interned threads are still eligible for GC

Comment: @JosephNields - Interned *Strings*.

Comment: @HotLicks derp. Obviously. Whoops

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems like it'd be pretty easy to do in non-native code ...

You're wrong. By specification, `String.intern()` must interact with the constant pool, to meet the requirement that 'all literal strings are interned'. That can't be done from Java code.

Comment: You could define things any way you like, but then it isn't Java any more. The JLS requires string literal constant pooling by the compiler.

Comment: That's it, there. Because it _must_ be done by the compiler, because there's no other way to define what " does without opening up the language to all sorts of things that would make no sense with the bigger picture. So the strings at compile time could go nowhere _but_ somewhere native, and there you have it.

Comment: Just because interning is required does not demand that the `intern` method be native.  After all, the JVM can call the `run` method of `Runnable` objects.  `intern` is native because it needs to be to access the required internal resources.